# grails module "app-name"-grailsPlugin isn't automatically loaded in IntelliJ on Windows but is on Mac

Tags: intellij-idea, java-8, maven-3, grails-plugin, grails-2.4

I am supposed to get a "app-name"-grailsPlugins folder/module under my project structure, however I am not getting it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4HKJ.png)

I am not sure if it's a maven issue, since I am getting a sucessful "maven compile" as well as "grails compile" but my friend is able to get it on his mac.

Because of that IntelliJ isn't able to recognize a valid class from the spring-security-core plugin. It doesn't affects me as much as of now, but I shouldn't have any line of code "redlined" and IntelliJ should be able to recognize that class.

This is my dependency within the pom.xml:

```
      <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
      <version>${grails.spring-security.version}</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
      <type>zip</type>
      <exclusions>
        <!--<exclusion>
          &lt;!&ndash; can make global exclusion in BuildConfig &ndash;&gt;
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>-->
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
          <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Any help is appreciated. I have been looking everywhere so far.

[Screenshot of project structure with missing grailsPlugins module with maven 3.8.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AerfA.png)

UPDATE

STEPS TO REPRODUCE

1. Install sdkman
2. Use sdkman to install Grails 2.4.5
3. Use Grails 2.4.5 command-line "grails create-app (name of your grails project)" to create grails project.
4. Open grails project inside IntelliJ
5. Go to terminal inside IntelliJ and use Grails command "grails create-pom (your chosen group id [com.samplemaven]) to create Maven pom.xml file.
6. Go to IntelliJ File|Project Structure | Module and you will see that IntelliJ doesn't automatically generate app-name-grailsPlugins module

[Sample Grails 2.4.5 project in IntelliJ with Maven integration](https://github.com/axelkouassi/sample-grails245-maven-intellij)

Comment: Please try File | Invalidate Caches | Invalidate and Restart.

If the issue remains, please provide a sample project illustrating the problem

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try that.

Comment: I have tried "File | Invalidate Caches | Invalidate and Restart" and it didn't work. I will test a sample project and see the result and keep you posted.

Comment: Please, share an example if possible as well. Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sending an example as well as steps to reproduce soon.

Comment: I have created a sample project on [link](github https://github.com/axelkouassi/sample-grails245-maven-intellij) @Konstantin Annikov

Comment: I have created a sample project on [link](github github.com/axelkouassi/sample-grails245-maven-intellij) @s0xzwasd